# Replace "bla": "*" to "bla": * with wildcards Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, wildcards

I've a lot of data in my Word file in I'll to replace some content. The content I'll replace is show in example below:

```
// original data I'll replace
{
    "nummer": "1",
    "jaar": "2010",
    "bedrijf": [
        {
            "naam": "a name",
            "prijs": "0,93"
        },
        {
            "naam": "a other name",
            "prijs": "0,87"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "nummer": "2",
    "jaar": "2010",
    "bedrijf": [
        {
           "naam": "a name",
           "prijs": "0,93"
        },
        {
            "naam": "a other name",
            "prijs": "0,87"
        }
    ]
} // and much more data
```

Now everything that match with `"nummer": "*"` (with wildcard), I'll replace with `"nummer": *` (also with wildcard).  Both wildcards must be equal to each other. Same for `"jaar": "*"` (wildcard).

I do this in two steps first `"nummer": "*"` to `"nummer": *` and second `"jaar": "*"` to `"jaar": *`

[image]

<sup><sup>1</sup> on screenshot is "Use wildcards" translated to "Jokertekens gebruiken"</sup>

I've try to check the option "Use wildcard"<sup>1</sup> and hope that it works like I'll to have but it isn't. Word replace everything like result below.

```
// how Word replace everyting
{
    "nummer": *,
    "jaar": *,
    "bedrijf": [
        {
            "naam": "a name",
            "prijs": "0,93"
        },
        {
            "naam": "a other name",
            "prijs": "0,87"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "nummer": *,
    "jaar": *,
    "bedrijf": [
        {
           "naam": "a name",
           "prijs": "0,93"
        },
        {
            "naam": "a other name",
            "prijs": "0,87"
        }
    ]
} // and much more data
```

But that's not the result I'll to have. It must be like data below:

```
// What I'll to have
{
    "nummer": 1,
    "jaar": 2010,
    "bedrijf": [
        {
            "naam": "a name",
            "prijs": "0,93"
        },
        {
            "naam": "a other name",
            "prijs": "0,87"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "nummer": 2,
    "jaar": 2010,
    "bedrijf": [
        {
           "naam": "a name",
           "prijs": "0,93"
        },
        {
            "naam": "a other name",
            "prijs": "0,87"
        }
    ]
} // and much more data
```

How could I do this in Word 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the quotes from around numbers, enter

```
"([0-9]@)"
```

in search box, and

```
\1
```

in the replace box.

The parentheses `( )` surround a group to be matched, `[0-9]` means a character in the range "0" to "9", and the "@" means "one or more occurrences of the previous character or expression." The `\1` represents whatever was found in the first set of parentheses.

For more information, please see [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f?CorrelationId=71982070-8c11-46de-9628-f54553c86504&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

If you require the numbers-in-quotes to be after a colon and a space, it will need a little bit more work.

N.B. I do not have Word available to check this answer.