# Replace with wildcards in Excel or batch edit some wrapping formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, find-and-replace

I'm only trying to delete some `CONCATENATE()` function from some formulas in Excel.

What I have; here 'Something' could be a lot of things (digits, <, >, texts, etc…

```
CONCATENATE("Something = "; SUM(A1:A30))
```

What I want:

```
SUM(A1:A30)
```

And it seems *very* complicated!

I've tried with the search and replace functionality but even as stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1125293/ms-office-how-to-replace-with-wildcard-string) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1057578/replace-bla-to-bla-with-wildcards-word-2016) the wildcard `\number` doesn't seem to work.

What I've tried:

Search:

```
CONCATENATE("*= ";*))
```

Replace:

```
\2
```

But it only replace with exactly `\2` and not the `SUM(...)`

I've also tried to 'group' the matching characters with surrounding parenthesis : `CONCATENATE("(*)= ";(*)))` but it doesn't find anything.

I thought I could do this in 2 steps : first just replace the begining with nothing `CONCATENATE("*= ";` and then get rid of the final parenthesis. But Excel won't accept this and I got "There's a problem with this formula" alert dialog.

---

**Edit**: Trying to follow @Mayukh’s instructions:

[image]

Comment: Probably using `LAMBDA()` with `Evaluate()` which is a `Macro 4.0 Formula` also requires to save the file as `Macro enabled`. Could try by defining in the name manager as `EVAL()` which refers to `=LAMBDA(α,Evaluate(α))` and then use `=EVAL(TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(C2,")",-1),"; "))` also you can refer this post. **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76995534/8162520)** note here `C2` refer to `FORMULATEXT()` returned `=CONCATENATE("Something = "; SUM(A1:A30))`

Comment: Hmmm I don't really get what you suggest ... I've tried the worflow on the link you provided to "define Name" But `=LAMBDA(α,Evaluate(α))`seems not to be an ok formula... I have the "There's a problem with this formula"

Comment: The said formulas works with `MS365` ! What is your `Excel Version`?

Comment: I have Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20194) 64 bits

Comment: Great! The first goto `Name Manager` --> Click on `New` --> `Name` it as `EVAL` and in refers to write `=LAMBDA(α,EVALUATE(α))` and now in the worksheet, apply the formula as `=EVAL()` within the brackets enter the formula returned value which is enclosed within `=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(FormulaTextReturned,")",-1),"; "))` note the last delimiter for `TEXTAFTER()` may differ, because i have taken it as `semicolon` as per the post, it may be different

Comment: Please see the question's edit and the error I face :/

Comment: I see, may be in place of comma you need to use semicolon as separator it depends on regional settings. as you can see here it works on my end: **[Check](https://imgur.com/gallery/3idb8ZC)**

Comment: Have you tried to change the comma to semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

Not using **`VBA`** but using **`Excel`**<sup>**4.0**</sup> **`Macro Functions`** with **`Modern Excel Functions - MS365`** is one way of doing this. Although the workbook needs to be saved as either **`.xlsm`** or **`.xlsb`**

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C4</kbd>

```
=EVAL(TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(C2,")",-1),"; "))
```

---

Where `EVAL()` is a defined-named function which refers to:

```
=LAMBDA(α,EVALUATE(α))
```

---

Reference to a solution posted earlier in `StackOverflow` --> **[Text Maths Equation To Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76994316/text-maths-equation-to-formula/76995534#76995534)** which is commented above.

---

Also read here on the same **MSFT Documentations** -- **[Exel 4.0 Macro Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/working-with-excel-4-0-macros-ba8924d4-e157-4bb2-8d76-2c07ff02e0b8)**

---

List of all the **`Excel`**<sup>**4.0**</sup> **`Macro Functions`** can be found **[here](https://exceloffthegrid.com/using-excel-4-macro-functions/)**

---

**Note:** Separators may differ as per one's regional settings. For me it is comma, but for OP as it seems could be `semi-colon` --> `;` or `dot` --> `.` or `Slash` --> `\` . For more clarity one can read here on **[International-Delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120417/horizontal-vs-vertical-array-delimiters-international)**

---